# Can't understand why my sort algorithm is so slow

Tags: java

So I'm playing around with quick sort and I've noticed something strange, anytime I go over 10 values to sort, the sorting takes a VERY long time, compared to something like insertion sort. Can someone explain why it so so slow anytime I ask it to sort more than 10 values? Maybe it's something to do with the code.

EDIT. I've made some changes and now I'm getting stack overflow errors, great.

```
       public class quicksorttest{
   public static void main(String args[]){
      int array[] = new int[100];
      for(int a =0; a<array.length;a++){
         array[a] = (int)(Math.random()*100);
      }

      quickSort(array,0,array.length);
   }

   public static void quickSort(int array[],int p, int q){
    if(q-p <=1);//skip

    else{
        int x; int i,j,k;
        //let x = middle element in f[p..q-1]. 

        x= array[(p+q/2)];
        i=p;j=p;k=q;
        while(j!=k){
            if(array[j]==x)
                j=j+1;
            else if(array[j]<x){    //swap array[j] with array[i]
                int temp =array[j];
                array[j] = array[i]; array[i]=temp;
                j=j+1;i=i+1;

            }
            else{//array[j]>x
                //swap array[j[ with array[k-1]
                int temp = array[j]; 
                array[j] = array[k-1]; array[k-1]=temp;
                k=k-1;
            }
        }

        quickSort(array,p,i);
        quickSort(array,j,q);

    }
   }
}
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: Use the eclipse (or whatever you use) debugger and step through your code. This should make it pretty easy to see why your algorithm is taking so long to complete.

Comment: Sorry about the indentation. I have never really delved in the debugger before but I shall give it a try.

Comment: Also read up on Java coding conventions (camel case, upper vs. lower case).

Comment: Does 'take very long' mean that it doesn't terminate? I have the feeling that at least one of the conditions comparing against the pivot should be `<=` or `>=` instead of only `<` or `>` because that way the algorithm may deadlock.

Comment: Yes I mean terminate. I may try that. Also thanks Starblue I will check that.

Comment: Why don't you just implement Quicksort like it's described in every textbook? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

Answer (score 0):

The way I approach algorithms, and **recursive** algorithms in particular is to follow the following rough plan:

- start with an empty array
- try an array with 1 element
- try an array with 2 elements (these first three are important because they're typically the end state for a recursive method/)
- try an array with 3 or 4 elements, but try the same set for a while so that you can reproduce your results. If you get a failure with a random set but it works on the next run you may not know if you've fixed the issue or it was the data you were trying

Only once you have the above working repeatedly should you try larger data sets, and then finally try randomized data.

In your case there are few small problems, but small problems in a recursive problem can multiply! :-)

To start with, try the above - if you still get stuck a really nice simple implemention can be found on: [Bob Sedgewicks algorithm site](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/23quicksort/Quick.java.html)

Its worth adding System.out.println statements (for small data sets - for large ones this is less useful), or better yet stepping through with a debugger (IntelliJ, Eclipse, Netbeans etc)

Comment: So I can get it working with small datasets, but when I go above I get arrayindexoutofbounds errors